# Display key/value pair for SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: jquery, json

I am using SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC to return an array in PHP to an ajax call.

I would like to then reference a particular item in the array.

So my PHP json is:

```
$sth = sqlsrv_query($conn,"SELECT Property, Value from TBL_CONFIG_SYSTEM");

    $rows = array();
while($r = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sth,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}    
print json_encode($rows);
```

and I would like to do something like this for my ajax response:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'json/admin/getSystemSettings.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {},
    success: function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (key, value) {
            console.log('key: ' + key + ',value: ' + value);
        });
    }
});
```

The console log seems to just return:

```
index: 0,value: [object Object]
index: 1,value: [object Object]
index: 2,value: [object Object]
index: 3,value: [object Object]
index: 4,value: [object Object]
```

I would like this to return the data from the array, not the index and object?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: sorry. Just updated it - I forgot that bit! :)

Comment: Removed irrelevant tags. You can't blame your server-side database library for your client-side JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log()` is useless if you convert everything to string. For proper debugging you need one of these:

```
console.log('key: %o, value: %o', key, value);
```

... or, if your browser console doesn't support Firebug API:

```
console.log('key: ', key, ',value: ', value);
```

You should also inspect your actual JSON (either from PHP or with your browser developer tools). I suppose yours looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Property": "Foo 1",
        "Value" : "Bar 1",
    },
    {
        "Property": "Foo 2",
        "Value" : "Bar 2",
    },
    {
        "Property": "Foo 3",
        "Value" : "Bar 3",
    }
]
```

Thus key is irrelevant and you need to use `value.Property` and `value.Value`.